# Tomcat: Forward Session Id to another Tomcat (without session data)

Tags: java, session, tomcat

Is it possible to "forward" just the session id from Tomcat A to Tomcat B as follows

```
Browser --> Tomcat A --> Tomcat B
```

where `-->` denotes a HTTP request?

The idea is that while A and B are independent servers with independent session data, I would like to archive a global session id per browser across distinct Tomcat web applications (similar to A as a "proxy").

The idea is as follows: When the Browser does a Request without a session, it should generate a fresh one, e.g. with `id=abc`. Now when sending a request with the same session cookie `id=abc`, Tomcat B creates a new session with the same id (but with data distinct to A).

I looked at Tomcat's `SessionIdGenerator`, but the session id in B is dependent on the request and the generator looks like a singleton.
I have a feeling this requires a custom session manager in Tomcat B, as the session id cannot be modified.

An alternative approach is to maintain two seperate sessions, one for the browser and one for connections from A to B (where A stores the session id returned by B in the browser session attributes). However this would require additional state and thus would not be my favored solution.

Kudos if you can suggest a working solution for latest Tomcat 7.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the same session ID? Chances are you can do it without the id being the same.

Comment: I have two Enterprise Systems, a CMS and a Webshop, both running on seperate Tomcat Servers. I'm currently evaluating how to do session management when both servers must have their own session and one can talk to the other (e.g. A to B, not vice versa)

Comment: Doesn't seem that you need the same session id as one server will be a client to the other. Seems that the client will just have to manage a cookie per its own client session. But if the end client will be connecting directly to either server, maybe the two servers need session replication; or at least a cookie scoped to a domain applicable to both (easy to do with a reverse proxy if the application servers set and/or read the same cookie). I'd find it dodgy to interfere with session id generation, but there's also a lot I don't know...

Comment: The scenario is as follows: I would like to add some dynamic (user-specific) content blocks from the shop (B) to the CMS (A) using HTTP requests with a shop session. Think of customer names, delivery addresses, etc. That means either I have to remember the session id of the shop system in the CMS or I need a session identifier across all applications. Replication does not work as the applications are different.